# Spring Security - Disable SSL certification check

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have been working with some OAuth2 issues recently, and the Client library is Spring Security.

My project using Spring Cloud Gateway for its gateway service, I configured a Self-Signed SSL certification for this service, which certification is generated by "mkcert".

I found that Spring Security send "jwks validating request" and "required oauth2 token request" itself internally:

- https//:gateway-service/authorization-service/oauth2/token
- https//:gateway-service/authorization-service/.well-known/jwks.json

And it occurred SSLHandshakeException, for "jwks validating reques" is the way like:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_id_token] An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: 
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://gateway-service/authorization-service/.well-known/jwks.json": 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target;
nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

We can see its request is sent by RestTemplate (@see NimbusJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriJwtDecoderBuilder$restOperations), but I can't find a way to configure the RestTemplate or post process for it because it's instance by Spring Security itself, and it did't inject to SpringApplicationContext container...

Is there any solution to handle this exception?  Such like disable the SSL certification validation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the RestTemplate yourself and provide it as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.2/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-validation

```
    RestTemplate restOperations = new RestTemplate();
    // configure restOperations
    NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri("http://TODO").restOperations(restOperations).build();
    return jwtDecoder;
```

Comment: Seems like the answer you write is for OAuth2 Resource Server but not OAuth2 Client Server. Dependencies in my project about oauth2 is `spring-boot-starter-security` and `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`, and I have tried configuring with @Bean in the way you described, but it didn't work. In debug result, I found there were two NimbusJwtDecoder objects in the memory, the @Bean one is in SpringContext Container. The other one which instance by Spring Security itself didn't involve in the container and this is the effective one.

Comment: For login you can define a bean of type JwtDecoderFactory, which instantiates a JwtDecoder for a single ClientRegistration. see OidcIdTokenDecoderFactory for an example.

Comment: For client and resource server code examples see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8882

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
@Bean 
JwtDecoderFactory<ClientRegistration> jwtDecoderFactory() {
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkSetUri)
            .restOperations(restOperations).build();
    return (clientRegistration) -> jwtDecoder;
}
```

source:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10334